# system file removed after sudo apt-get remove python

Tags: ubuntu

This is a big mistake I made.I'm just thinking to remove python and reinstall it,but end up my whole system is no longer functional , it seems everything is removed.

I'm trying to sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop in the login-screen(Alt+ctrl+F1),but I unable to connect to network at all,hence everything just failed to fetch.After restart it just stuck at loading page.

Is there anything else I can do?Please help.Thank you.

P.S. Wonder if boot repair works,I'm downloading it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found which I would like to share with others.

References link: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1606409.html

Firstly, since I can't connect to the Internet I run the following command:

```
sudo dhclient -r;sudo dhclient
```

And now it is connected. After that, just follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-standard meta-package
```

And my Ubuntu is recovered.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the dhclient I was lost wondering why the internet wasn't working.

Comment: `sudo dhclient -r;sudo dhclient` is THE key

Comment: you saved me, i executed `sudo apt remove --auto-remove libpython3.6-stdlib` and everything was removed i knew i was doomed when i saw the quantity of the package being removed, the laptop will only boot in terminal mode, your answer helped get back to the desktop mode

Answer (score 2):

Apt-get is python based, and removing it probably broke quite a few things. I'd strongly recommend backing up your /home, /etc and anything else you value and reinstalling. Then you can copy back /home and /etc

You could, alternately boot into a livecd, and set up a chroot, then run apt from the livecd, but this is likely to be far too much work. Askubuntu has instructions on [setting up chroot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels), and once this is done, try running `apt-get install python` (and ubuntu desktop and everything else you need. Then reboot, and cross your fingers that it worked.

Comment: So sorry for delayed response,and thank you so much for your reply.I found a solution for my problem,however the link given is so details and gotta learn from it too.Thank again.

Comment: Who'd know APT-GET is Python based.. crap! Thx!